# Rotating a Point From a Point, not Center

Tags: geometry

Lets say i have point as P(x1,y1) and another point P(x2,y2). I want to rotate P(x1,y1) with lets say 10 degrees around P(x2,y2) to find P(x3,y3) . How can i do that in an programming language logic? thanks...

Comment: Use a rotation matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First **translate** point (x2, y2) to the origin.  That would take (x1, y1) to (x1- x2, y1- y2\

Then use the rotation matrix $\begin{bmatrix}cos(\theta) & sin(\theta) \\ -sin(\theta) & cos(\theta) \end{bmatrix}$.

$\begin{bmatrix}cos(\theta) & sin(\theta) \\ -sin(\theta) & cos(\theta) \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x1- x2 \\ y1- y2\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} cos(\theta)(x1- x2)- sin(\theta)(y1- y2) \\ sin(\theta)(x1- x2)+ cos(\theta)(y1- y2)\end{bmatrix}$

Finally, translate back by adding (x2, y2):
$(x3, y3)= (cos(\theta)(x1- x2)- sin(\theta)(y1- y2)+ x2, sin(\theta)(x1- x2)+ cos(\theta)(y1- y2)+ y2)$

Answer (score 0):

First calculate the distance between the two points

$$||P_2 - P_1|| = \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$$

And then the angle of $\overline{P_1P_2}$ and the horizontal line at $P_1$

\begin{align*}
\alpha &= arcsin\frac{y_2-y_1}{||P_2 - P_1||}\\
\alpha &= arccos\frac{x_2-x_1}{||P_2 - P_1||}
\end{align*}

If you want to rotate this point now by some $\beta$, then the new point will be at

$$(x_1 + cos(\alpha+\beta)||P_2 - P_1||,y_1 + sin(\alpha+\beta)||P_2 - P_1|| )$$

Answer (score 0):

$P_3=P_2+R(P_1-P_2),$ where

$$R=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\alpha & -\sin\alpha \\
\sin\alpha & \cos\alpha
\end{pmatrix}$$
is the rotation matrix which rotates points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ couter-clockwise with an angle $\alpha$.